# Free flash components to render graphic primitives from XML

Tags: xml, flash, drawing

Good day, everyone.

I need a compiled and ready-to-use Flash lib, which is able to draw in browser basic primitives (contours, points and labels, not just a charts), described in XML given to the script.
It is desirable that the library had at least basic functionality for styling displayed objects: gradients, borders, basic animation, HTML markup.
GPL and other free licenses are prefered.

Could you please give me advice (some variants) in this question?

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english and thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) (which is actually XML) you can use [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) for example.